# Why doesn't Encoding.default_external respect LANG?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

It's my understanding that Ruby's `Encoding.default_external` is given a default value based on the environment variables `LC_ALL` and `LANG`, giving precedence to the former. I've run into several bugs where the default external encoding somehow ends up set to ASCII even though the environment variables are set to UTF-8.

For example:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
irb(main):002:0> ENV['LC_ALL']
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> ENV['LANG']
=> "en_US.UTF-8"
```

In the environments where this has happened, I've also grepped through all the gems being loaded for any code manually setting the default external encoding, but haven't found anything. How is what I'm seeing above possible? I'm using Ruby 2.2 above, but I've seen this happen on all Ruby 2.x versions.

Comment: I suggest you to read this [excerpt](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WOyuE3YYjiIC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=local+encoding+environment+variable+Ruby&source=bl&ots=cujuVB-tTt&sig=4Kmtt9pROu1V4MH3p1UMMZT6gtM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AOq4VLiJLcXGuASRgoLQAQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=local%20encoding%20environment%20variable%20Ruby&f=false) from the book. It has great information about the encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. Not only does the `LANG` environment variable need to be set, but the locale it species must have been generated for the OS. On a stock Linux image, the default locale may be something that is not UTF-8. In my particular case, I'm using Debian 7.7 and the default locale is "POSIX". I was able to set the default locale by installing the locales package and following the interactive prompts to generate the en_US.UTF-8 locale:

```
$ apt-get -y install locales
```

If the locales package is already installed, you can just reconfigure it instead:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Now setting `LANG` will change the current system locale, and Ruby's `Encoding.default_external` will be set properly:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

For an example of how to automate the generation and configuration of the default locale instead of doing it interactively, take a look at [this Docker image](https://github.com/litaio/docker-ruby/blob/a1b803d6f0c12385395d8378caf9fb5404ca9e65/Dockerfile).

Comment: I have the same issue but this does not solve it, I still have US-ASCII after installing locales and set the LANG variable.